# Rare property of lim sup and lim inf?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\left\{f_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued functions on a measure space $(M, \mathcal{S})$. Then the functions
$$
\limsup _{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(x) \quad \text { and } \quad \liminf _{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(x)
$$
are also $\mathcal{S}$-measurable.

---

I already have proven this statement and my question is about something else. In the script it says that the reader may use the hint:

For a sequence $\left\{a_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers the following is true:
$$
\limsup _{k \rightarrow \infty} a_{k}=\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \max \left\{a_{k}, a_{k+1}, \ldots, a_{m}\right\}
$$

Now, I have not used this in my proof, but I can assure you, that my proof is airtight nonetheless. Anyway, can someone point out why this holds? I have not seen this equality before and did not know that one can present $\limsup, \liminf$ like that. I know that for a set of limit points $H$ we can say that $\limsup H = \max H$ and vice versa. I do not even see how this property can be useful for our proof.

Answer (score 1):

By definition
$$\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m\geq k} a_m),$$
so to prove the claim, it suffices to prove for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ that
$$\sup_{m\geq k}a_m = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \max(a_k, a_{k+1},\dots,a_{k+m}).$$

The reason that this representation is useful, is that
$m \mapsto \max(a_k,\dots,a_{k+m})$ is increasing, and
$k \mapsto \sup_{m\geq k} a_m$ is decreasing. So to prove that $\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} f_k$ is measurable, it suffices to show that the limit of monotone sequences of functions are measurable.